# PCAN USB QT Interfacing issue

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

I recently purchased one [PCAN USB device](http://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB.199.0.html?L=1). I am having trouble interfacing the APIs with my Qt GUI.

I am using `#include <libpcan.h>` and `#include <pcan.h>` in my code as mentioned in one sample code. I am compiling the code with `-lpcanfd` compiler flag . Once I add `#include <libpcan.h>` in the header and compile my `Qt` code I get an error like this:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qthread.h:53:16: error:
expected unqualified-id before 'void' static Qt::HANDLE
currentThreadId() Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
```

If i comment `#include <libpcan.h>` the compile process finished without error(s). Can anyone suggest me a solution? Without including `libpcan` header I won't be able to use the device.

Comment: Show us your progress so far and the provide a link to sample code.

Comment: I use same interface under linux and I had to create some soft using it. But, to create more generic soft, and also simplify development, I used [SocketCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN) instead of manufacturer library. It really easy, take a look ([Peak reference for socketcan](http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm))

Comment: This seems like something funny in `libpcan.h`. However, unless you have a very specific reason, just use SocketCAN for your CAN stuff, it has nice interface, nice tools for testing purposes etc, and it is CAN dongle vendor independent.

Comment: Most likely, the API exposed by `libpcan.h` puts some unsavory stuff in the global namespace and interferes with other code. You'll have to identify the unsavory bits and try to work around them. And perhaps complain to the vendor of the broken API so that they fix it.